# Stereo calibration accuracy not appearing

Tags: calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just did the calibration of my stereo rig following the instructions in [StereoCalibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) . According to the tutorial, after calibrating the reprojection error should appear in the top right area. But as you can see in the snapshot, this does not appear in my case:

[image: image description]

Why is this information not available to me? Is there any additional way in which I can calculate the accuracy of my calibration?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59101/stereo-calibration-accuracy-not-appearing/) by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should put the calibration pattern in view of the cameras; the stereo calibration error is computed based on calibration pattern detection.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on 2013-03-25**:
If I am not wrong, it is quite common to get a measure of the accuracy of a calibration by calculating the RMS of the reprojection error over the images used for calibration. Is there a simple way to calculate this in ROS?

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-04-04**:
What accuracy did you get for this one ?